# Setter not getting called for TextBox Text property in Data Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

In one of my Data Models I have a `string` property that is bound to the text of a `textBox`. When I change the text of this `textBox` I would like to update a property in another ViewModel. To achieve this, I believe that I would have to perform the operations under the property's setter, but whenever I change the `textbox`'s text the only area of the `string` property that is called is the getter. There must be something that I don't know or am overlooking..

This is the string property that I am working with just in case it helps to see it:

```
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return _displayName; }
    set
    {
        _displayName = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => DisplayName);

        //These values are from the other ViewModel
        if (MainTreeCollection.SelectedItem != null
               && value != MainTreeCollection.SelectedItem.DisplayName)
             MainTreeCollection.SelectedItem.DisplayName = value;
    }
}
```

I noticed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013208/how-can-i-tell-my-viewmodel-that-the-user-is-changing-text-in-the-textbox) he shows how to "get [his] ViewModel to know when the user has changed text in the `TextBox` and moved the focus away from the `TextBox`". It looks like he has achieved this by binding to a `string` property, which is what I did above.

**How come the property's setter is not getting accessed? How would I change my method and code to perform these operations?**

**Update:** This is the xaml of the `textBox` as requested:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.DisplayName}" Height="23"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="title_TB"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold"
         FontSize="14" Margin="5,2,0,0" />
```

Comment: Can you show the "setting" code (the actual assignment), or is this coming from the UI?

Comment: This is the code in the DataModel. You want the xaml of the `textBox`?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the binding?

Comment: @EricAfterDark so you're actually using DataBinding after all.. who would have thought....

Comment: @HighCore That is hilarious that I was just thinking about you. Of course.. I always use data binding!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want bounded property to be set while you are typing into it, set [**UpdateSourceTrigger**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to **`PropertyChanged`**.

Default value is **`LostFocus`** for TextBox i.e. bounded property gets updated only when LostFocus event gets raised for TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.DisplayName,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="title_TB"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold"
         FontSize="14" Margin="5,2,0,0"/>
```

Comment: So do I have to manually add in `LostFocus`? Or is adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` all I need to do?

Comment: Just set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` like I provided in the sample above. Nothing else required.

Comment: I did that, and then I set a break point in the setter of my property and it never gets called after editing and removing focus from my `textBox`. I wonder if something is wrong on my end...

Comment: @EricAfterDark check the Visual Studio output window to see if you have any binding errors...

Comment: Check your output window. I suspect binding is failing. Do you see any binding errors over there?

Comment: I checked, no binding errors relating to the textBox. If binding is failing, why does it still call the getter?

Comment: With the above being said, there is no way for me to add my code to the getter, because I will get a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @EricAfterDark hmmm... interesting.. I wonder if you're actually debugging the correct instance of `Model`?

Comment: Well I can't view separate instances in VS, can I? FYI, I'm running tests on the UserControl/DataModel that is active when the program starts. Everything else except this one is Dynamic.

Comment: @EricafterDark - With the posted code, it's hard to tell what's exactly wrong. Try to produce this issue in small sample code and in case you are able to produce it, post the code here for that. So, that we can help.